# import .csv into .db in python3

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I would much appreciate if you could help me with the issue. I want to import `.csv` (5 columns with data) data into `.db` format using Python. I took the script from here:

```
import sqlite3
import csv
class csvrd(object):
    def csvFile(self):
        self.readFile('c:/users/quant/desktop/trade.csv')
    def readFile(self, filename):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('c:/users/quant/desktop/ledger_4.db')
        cur = conn.cursor() 
        cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trading(date varchar,asset varchar,quant varchar,price varchar,com varchar)""")
        filename.encode('utf-8')
        print ("test1")
        with open(filename) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for field in reader:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO unicom VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);", field)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
c = csvrd().csvFile()
```

but unfortunately I get this:

> 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 62: character maps
>   to

Could you please advise what is wrong with the code or help with any other way to import the `csv`?
Thank you a lot in advance!

Thank you for your reply! A few rows from csv:

- date              asset            quant          price          com
- "08.08.2017
  11:35:49"  Башнефть а.о.   3   2 188,00    2,63
- "08.08.2017
  11:35:49"  Башнефть а.о.   3   2 188,00    2,63
- "08.08.2017
  11:35:49"  Башнефть а.о.   2   2 188,00    1,75

Comment: provide an example CSV file output? I assume it's something to do with non ASCII characters

Comment: `open()` has an encoding argument. Please post a few rows of CSV.

Answer (score 0):

according to [Encoding Problem: Double Mis-Conversion](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-double-conversion.html) perhaps you have to read file as byte and then replace `0x9D` with `0xC3` and then decode it